# How to set height in percentage when parent height is in min-height?

Tags: html, css

The something div grows to 150% of App div but App div doesn't grow to fit something div.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fcue0k2q/62/)

```css
/* Resetting margin */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,body,#root
{
  height: 100%;
}

.App {
  height:1px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.something {
  height: 150%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="App">
        <div class="something"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

As you can tell by the classes, this is actually for a React app. But my problem is that I set the html,body and root div to height:100%; . So next, i set my App div's min-height to min-height:100%; and then I set background-color: green; to the App div cause I want it to have a backgound color. But, setting height:150%;on the something div doesn't work. I found out that it requires the parent div to have a height. So, from a google search, i discovered that setting height:1px; on App div fixes it. I got the 150% value from the App div, but the App div itself doesn't grow to fit the something div's 150% height. How can i fix this?

Comment: You've got your parents `html, body, #root` set explicitly to `100%`, if we add a border to each individually with a different color we see that sets up your boundary to the viewport area. Are you ultimately just trying get the child height to match the parents because I'm not entirely understanding the intent but the 1px hacks and stuff are usually not necessary these days.

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes! I want the `.App` div  to be atleast as tall as the viewport initially. Setting 100vh is an option, but it causes problems on mobile devices.

Comment: what you want is not possible, if you want an element to be 150% its parent height it means you will always have 50% of overflow. The parent cannot grow to fit the new height because your 150% will make no more sense